# How do I mock a service dependency in Angular with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I've been googling this for a while and there's no quick concise answer to something that I'd consider pretty trivial.

I have a service `serviceToTest`, which has a dependency `serviceDep` which is injected via Angular's DI.

The service looks something like this

```
export class ServiceToTest {
    constructor(private _dep: ServiceDep){}

    serviceMethod() {};
}
```

I want to unit test the `serviceMethod` method, and to do that I need to instantiate the service and mock the dependency. The dependency doesn't need to do anything other than allow the instantiation of the service. The method I want to test doesn't require the dependency to be executed.

How can I set up a mock so that I can satisfy the service's constructor?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-a-dependency Read from Component with a dependency to Async test with fakeAsync()

Comment: Great point, `fakeAsync` is for use when you need to have control over the async zone. I think Jake shouldn't need to use it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own mock service in place of the actual service:

```
describe('ServiceToTest ', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [],
    providers: [{ provide: ServiceToTest, useClass: ServiceToTestMock }]
  }));
```

Comment: But what do I use to instantiate the instance of the mock `ServiceToTestMock`?

Comment: @Jake12342134 It's injected in place of `ServiceToTest` (you don't need an instance), `ServiceToTestMock` could be as simple as `class ServiceToTestMock{}` if you don't need any actual methods to be called

Answer (score 0):

Some options below.

**Option one**:

The [Angular recommended way](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services) to do this is via **spies**:

```
it('should return value', () => {
  const serviceDepSpy = spyOn(Testbed.inject(ServiceDep), 'serviceMethod').returnValue(of(MOCK_VALUE));

  component.ngOnInit(); // assuming your method is called on init. 

  expect(serviceDepSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I quote:

> Prefer spies as they are usually the easiest way to mock services.

This allows you to mock easily at the unit test level (in each of your tests) and avoid overriding the mocked service (if you go with a `useClass` approach this can easily become an issue.

**Option two**:

`useClass`

This tends to work best **when you will always return the same value** in each of your test cases. If you need different mock values in each test, I'd go with spies.

**Option three**

`useValue`
This works best when you need to hard code a value or imported mock object and use the same mock value in all test cases. Like `useClass` it can be tricky to override.